# JSF: My dynamically added elements don't react

Tags: jsf

This questions seems to be so simple, yet I didn't find the mistake.

Ok, here we go: I have a form with a List of IPs (whatever),
**IP n**: [INPUT-FIELD] [Button "Add"]
**IP n+1**: [INPUT-FIELD] [Button "Add"]
These IPs exist right from the start.
They are initialized in the Constructor of the Managed Bean.

When I click on the "Add" Button, the current IP is validated. After that
I add another entry to my java.util.List and another line in the 
JSF form appears:

**IP n+2**: [INPUT-Field] [Button "Add"]

and so on.

Adding a line (with a new IP) and validating the current IP
work perfect for the existing values **IP n** and **IP n+1**,
but validating and adding does NOT work with the dynamically 
added **IP n+2**. Neither validating the dynamically generated input field 
works nor adding another line with the newly created "Add"-Button.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<h:form id="frmSpecial" prependId="false">
    <h:panelGroup id="tblDestFw">
        <c:forEach items="#{bean.fwdest}" var="fwdest">
            IP: <h:inputText value="#{fwdest.ip}" validator="#{bean.validateIP}"/>
            <h:commandButton action="#{bean.addFwDest()}" 
                             value="&gt;&gt;" title="Add another line">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="tblDestFw"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <br/>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>

@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@ViewScoped
public class EnterNewSystemFW implements Serializable {
     List<FirewallDest> fwdest;
     public EnterNewSystemFW() {
         fwdest.add(new FirewallDest("N"));
         fwdest.add(new FirewallDest("N+1"));
     }

     public void addFwDest() {
         fwdest.add(new FirewallDest());
     }
}
```

Thanks.

Bernd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to adding the new line, your `<c:forEach>` references a view scoped bean property. Due to [JSF issue 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492), this bean is reconstructed on **every** request.

Replace it by a normal JSF component like `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>` and it'll work as expected.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.fwdest}" var="fwdest">
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

As to performing validation, your `<f:ajax execute="@this">` processes only the current component (the command button), not the inputs. Use `<f:ajax execute="@form">` instead to process the entire form.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)